# Apache dynamic paths with SSLRequire and dynamic aliases

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-ssl

I have Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) serving some content to different customers based on their SSL certificate that we issue out. If the `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU` matches the OU in client's cert, then they will be allowed access to `/mydir/customerfolders/<OU>` on the webserver.

Each customer's cert contains a unique OU that matches folders under `/mydir/customerfolders/<OU>`  on the webserver.

Example scenario: cust1 has our certificate that contain `OU=cust1` , so they will be allowed access to `https://mywebserver/customerfolders/cust1` , which is basically a folder on our webserver :  `/mydir/customerfolders/cust1` .

I have been successful in creating dynamic aliases using `AliasMatch` that will redirect the url to the right folder, however I'd like to take it one step further  by redirecting the dynamic alias to a dynamic path - instead of having to define individual `<Directory>` stanza for each customer's folder.

Something like :

```
AliasMatch "^/customerfolders/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)" "/mydir/customerfolders/$1/$2"

<Directory "/mydir/customerfolders/$1">
   SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "MyCompany" \
   and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"$1"}
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I have tried the above but got a Forbidden Request and the SSL error log has the following :

`[Tue Jun 09 08:53:24.624038 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 24991] [client IPADDRESSS:49880] AH02229: access to /mydir/customerfolders/cust1 failed, reason: SSL requirement expression not fulfilled`

I'm not really sure if the above method if possible or if I'm using it the right way.
I want to utilize `Rewrite` but unsure how to tacke it with the `SSLRequire` directive.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
I'm almost there...I just need the right regex for this :

```
    SSLRequire %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/mydir/%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}/(.*)#
```

Currently the above gave me an error:

```
Failed expression: %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/mydir/%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}/(.*)#
```

How can I change the regex so that it matches `REQUEST_URI` (which should be `/mydir/%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}/test.html`
Thanks
J

UPDATED!!
Thank you Mr. White!
I have tried your code as below :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^(/myserver/%{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}/.*)" [NC]
RewriteRule "^/mydir/(.*)$" "/myserver/mydir/$1"

   <Directory "/myserver/mydir">
        AllowOverride None
        SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "MyCompany" \
              and %{REQUEST_URI}@@%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} =~ m#^/soc/([^/]+)/(.*)@@\1#
              and %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} eq "MyCA"
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

However, it is failing with the error:

```
SSLRequire: syntax error, unexpected T_ERROR: Parse error near '@'
```

What have I done wrong here..? :(
All I'm trying to do is allow access to the right directories under /myserver/mydir (eg /myserver/mydir/cust1) based on the OU ....

I really appreciate your input.

Thanks J

Comment: Bump...anyone? Would really appreciate some feedback

Comment: Adding double quotes around the left hand side, and using different delimiter characters works for me:  "%{DOCUMENT_URI}?&?%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_UID}" =~ m#^/absolute/path/([^/]+)/.*\?\&\?\1#   Also prefer DOCUMENT_URI over REQUEST_URI to rule out all request parameters from the regex, which should be ^ anchored of course. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SSLRequire %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/mydir/%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}/(.*)#
> ```

I don't believe you can't use a server variable (using `%{var}` syntax) directly in a regex like that (it's not valid *regex* syntax).

Maybe try something like the following instead:

```
SSLRequire %{REQUEST_URI}@@%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} =~ m#^/mydir/([^/]+)/(.*)@@\1#
```

Where `\1` is an internal backreference to the first captured group (ie. `([^/]+)`) which matches against `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU}`. `@@` is just some arbitrary string that does not occur in the pattern.

This assumes `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU` contains a string of the form `cust1` - which does not contain slashes.

However, this is based on your code attempt, which appears to contradict with what you stated in the first part of the question: `/mydir/customerfolders/<OU>`?

Although, shouldn't you be using the new syntax... `Require expr`?

> ```
> SSLRequire is deprecated and should in general be replaced by Require expr.
> ```

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! Still errors though..updated my question above.